# opencv warpAffine precision

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I am trying to use OpenCVs warpAffine to transform an image. I use the bilinear interpolation option (set by default). When using a very small transformation (e.g., translation of 0.01 pixel), the transformed image is *exactly* identical to the original. This is problematic since I need a big precision as further computations are performed on the transformed image.

Example:

```
Mat img_test = (Mat_<double>(5,5) << 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
Mat tfm; Mat transf_img_test;
tfm = Mat::eye(2,3,CV_64F);
tfm.at<double>(0,2) = 0.01;
warpAffine( img_test, transf_img_test, tfm, img_test.size(), INTER_LINEAR);
cout << "Original = " << img_test << endl;
cout << "Transformed = " << transf_img_test << endl;
```

The two images are exactly identical:

```
Original = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
            0, 0, 1, 0, 0;
            0, 0, 1, 0, 0;
            0, 0, 1, 0, 0;
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Transformed = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
               0, 0, 1, 0, 0;
               0, 0, 1, 0, 0;
               0, 0, 1, 0, 0;
               0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Note that when I set

```
tfm.at<double>(0,2) = 0.5,
```

instead, warpAffine correctly transforms (and interpolates) the image.

Comment: Are you sure that transf_img_test is CV_64F as well?

Comment: Yes. I have
transf_img_test.type() = 6
which corresponds to CV_64F

Comment: I don't see any obvious error, I think it should work. Maybe you can try other values between 0.5 and 0.01 to see when stops working, it hay give you some clue. You can take a look at the source code of OpenCV, but there are several implementations (cuda, opencl).

Comment: Looking at the code in https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp there is a suspicious `round_delta` that may have something to do with your problem (I don't understand very well all the code). I would try putting values higher than 1 (for example 100) in the img_test  matrix to see if it works better.

Comment: Thanks. The same exact problem persists when putting values significantly higher (or lower) than 1.